# How can I have an array of objects (with the same interface) but allow those objects to have additional common properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, oop, interface

I'm having an interface:

```
export interface StandardDescription {
  readonly financialAccountDescriptionDescription?: string;
  readonly financialAccountDescriptionId?: number;
}
```

I want to make an array that can hold many `StandardDescription` objects:

```
export const standardDescriptions: StandardDescription[] = [];
```

And I can do this fine:

```
export const standardDescriptions: StandardDescription[] = [
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "foo",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 1,
    },
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "bar",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 2,
    },
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "baz",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 3,
    }
];
```

---

...but I also want to each object to have common *additional* properties, such as a `hovercraftWithEels: number` value:

```
const standardDescriptions: StandardDescription[] = [
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "foo",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 1,
        hovercraftWithEels: 123
    },
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "bar",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 2,
        hovercraftWithEels: 456
    },
    {
        financialAccountDescriptionDescription: "baz",
        financialAccountDescriptionId: 3,
        hovercraftWithEels: 789
    }
];
```

However I get this error:

> Type `{ financialAccountDescriptionDescription: string; financialAccountDescriptionId: number; hovercraftWithEels: number; }` is not assignable to type `StandardDescription`.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and `hovercraftWithEels` does not exist in type `StandardDescription`.

How can I store *larger* objects in an array of *smaller types*?

Comment: If your interface is `interface myInterface { foo: string; }`, then you do `x.push({ foo: 'bar', baz: 42 })`…?!

Comment: `x: myInterface[] = []` **does not** “make an instance” of your interface. It’s creating an empty array that _can hold_ an object implementing your interface.

Comment: You’ll want something like `type Foo = MyInterface | { newProperty: string; };` and then your array is `const myArray: Foo[] = [];`. Watch-out for array contravariance though (you can avoid that by declaring `readonly Foo[]` but you can’t use that with an empty array: you’ll need to type-assert an existing array or array-like object).

Comment: @Dai The problem exactly is I don't want OR ( | ), I want both MyInterface  properties AND newProperty.

Comment: @deceze I can do that if my `x` type is `any`,  but when I'm trying to push an object, to an array with a specific type, I CAN'T push properties that doesn't exist in that type.

Comment: @Qiimiia I typod. Use `&` instead: `type Foo = MyInterface & { newProperty: string; };`

Comment: Whatever you put into that array *can* contain any properties you want, as long as it *at least* conforms to the interface! You won't be able to type-safely *access* those properties, as you did not type the array to guarantee that any properties beyond `myInterface` exist in it.

Comment: I update my question guyz. Please take a look.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Actually it DOES work! thanks @Dai